How to fix NullPointerException on Camunda Spring Boot JobWorker
I have the below implementation of a job worker.
@Component
public class UpdateHandler {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UpdateHandler.class);

    @JobWorker(type = "updateCaseStatus", autoComplete = false)
    public void handle(JobClient client, ActivatedJob job) {
        log.info("Handling update case status for process instance {}", job.getProcessInstanceKey());
        Map<String, Object> variables = job.getVariablesAsMap();
        String caseId = (String) variables.get("caseId");
        log.info("Updated case status for process instance {} and case id: {}", job.getProcessInstanceKey(), caseId);
        client.newCompleteCommand(job).send();
    }
}

This is my pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.camunda.community.examples</groupId>
    <artifactId>camunda-8-start-form</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
        <spring-boot.version>3.2.5</spring-boot.version>
        <spring-zeebe.version>8.4.2</spring-zeebe.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Camunda Zeebe Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.camunda</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-zeebe-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-zeebe.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Maven Compiler Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-parameters</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Spring Boot Maven Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Exec Maven Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.camunda.community.examples.StartFormProcessApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

But when I trying to run the application the following error occurs:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot load from object array because "parameterNames" is null.

The problem seems to be the annotation @JobWorker. Could you help me please?
